# Why some objects are not mirrored?

Tags: mesh, objects, mirror

I copied original objects and mirrored them. But one object never be mirrored. Why does it happen?
[image: The black]

The black colour is the original object, and the selected meshes are what I duplicated, and mirrored. However, the middle triangle never get mirrored. I do not know why? every object has the same pivot point (Center) what should I adjust to solve this problem?

Comment: How exactly are you mirroring these?

Comment: plz attach the file for detail investigation

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I just selected objects, and pressed Ctrl+D, and clicked [mirror]button on the left side panel (which shows up when I press T), and pressed 'Y'

Comment: @ateks I just put the file here, really don't know why it does not work.... [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3215" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3215/)

Comment: @Poa are you using mirror modifier

Comment: If yes then delete the half. And the part which you want to mirror is loose or say separate parts so join Ctrl+L and make it one mesh and then mirror it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways you can mirror

1st method : If yes then delete the half. And the part which you want to mirror is loose or say separate parts so join Ctrl+L and make it one mesh and then mirror it.

or if you do not want to join and keep separate

2nd method : Just group the half you want to mirror. with selected half group press shift+D and without moving just rotate 180 on x axis. (As the 3d cursor is set)

[image]

Comment: Oh the second method is really good for me! Since I have to keep the object separately! Thank you a lot :D

Comment: Hope it is helpful for you and others

Comment: @Poa if the answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted, or if it helped you at least upvote it.